# How to achieve has many through relation between users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am building matching system between users, originally it was has and belongs to many association, but due to some validations and additional data i need for that join table, i need to have model for that one, and change it to has many through.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many(:likes,
    class_name: :User,
    join_table: :user_likes,
    foreign_key: :user_liker_id,
    association_foreign_key: :user_liked_id)

has_and_belongs_to_many(:likeds,
    class_name: :User,
    join_table: :user_likes,
    foreign_key: :user_liked_id,
    association_foreign_key: :user_liker_id)
```

This is old implementation which needs to be converted to has_many through. As you can see, with this one i can retrieve all users which i liked and users which liked me. I have created `UserLike` model but i don't have any success with making it workable inside user model. What i already tried is following:

user.rb

```
has_many :user_likes
has_many :likes, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liked_id
has_many :likeds, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liker_id
```

user_like.rb

```
class UserLike < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This implementation raises following exception:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "like" or :likes in model UserLike. Try 'has_many :likes, :through => :user_likes, :source => '. Is it one of user or user_likes?

I don't know what i am missing here, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Try specifying `class_name: 'User'` to both the associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a join table that joins the same table twice you need two separate associations since the user can be in either foreign key:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes_as_liker,
    class_name: 'Like',
    foreign_key: 'liker_id'
  has_many :likes_as_liked,
    class_name: 'Like',
    foreign_key: 'liked_id'
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :liked, class_name: 'User'
end
```

With our two has_many associations done we can start creating indirect associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes_as_liker,
    class_name: 'Like',
    foreign_key: 'liker_id'
  has_many :likes_as_liked,
    class_name: 'Like',
    foreign_key: 'liked_id'
  has_many :likers,
    through: :likes_as_liked
  has_many :liked_users,
      through: :likes_as_liker,
      source: :liked
end
```

Which works perfectly:

```
irb(main):002:0> u.likers
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "likes" ON "users"."id" = "likes"."liker_id" WHERE "likes"."liked_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["liked_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
irb(main):003:0> u.liked_users
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "likes" ON "users"."id" = "likes"."liked_id" WHERE "likes"."liker_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["liker_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Comment: I took some liberties with the naming since it was more complicated than it really needs to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, with minor changes, i got it working. BTW do you have an idea with this implementation, how i could retrieve lets say, number of matched users and users with no matches at all?

Comment: Thats really the subject of a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description mentioned in the post you are trying to find the users which have liked my post and the users whom I have liked.

Below mentioned code does not tell rails that likes and likeds are actually users.

```
has_many :user_likes
has_many :likes, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liked_id
has_many :likeds, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liker_id
```

Modify it to below

```
has_many :user_likes
has_many :likes, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liked_id, source: :liked
has_many :likeds, through: :user_likes, foreign_key: :user_liker_id, source: :liked
```

Best Approach is specifying class along with class name so that rails know in which class is mapped to this foreign key when specifying customized relation names

When your association name is different than the name used at the :through you have to define the source parameter. If you look at the exception message it explicitly asks you to do it.

Hope it answers the question.